# Formula Parse Error - unable to work out why

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use the importxml function on Google Sheets on this page:

```
https://www.attheraces.com/racecard/Ayr/15-February-2022/1320
```

Essentially I want to import the "Forecast" bit that's down the page a little.  I have been using this formula:

```
=importxml("https://www.attheraces.com/racecard/Ayr/15-February-2022/1320", "//*[@id="forecast"]/p[2]/strong")
```

here is a picture of the developer tools:

[image: ATR]

I assumed that I could just copy the XPath and add it to my URL, but it doesn't appear to be working.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `//*[@id="forecast"]/p[2]` if you want the word "forecast" as well as the forecast data,
- Use `//*[@id="forecast"]/p[2]/text()` if you just want the forecast data (though it includes a blank row)

Your xPath `"//*[@id="forecast"]/p[2]/strong"` includes the strong attribute which adds nothing to define the location of the data or the data itself.

---

**XPATH & Double and Single quotes**

- If `IMPORTXML` is referencing a cell value (such as `=importxml(B1,B2)` where the value is Cell B2 is `//*[@id="forecast"]/p[2]` then IMPORTXML will parse the XPath with no problem. **BUT**
- If `IMPORTXML` contains an actual XPath value included in double quotes (such as `=importxml("https://www.attheraces.com/racecard/Chelmsford-City/17-February-2022/1700","//*[@id="forecast"]/p[2]")', there will be a parse error. This is because there` IMPORTXML` doesn't expect more than the opening/closing set of double quotes. In this case, change any other sets of double quotes to single quotes.

  - `=importxml("https://www.attheraces.com/racecard/Chelmsford-City/17-February-2022/1700","//*[@id='forecast']/p[2]")`

---

**Examples**

`//*[@id="forecast"]/p[2]`

[image: Forecast p2]

---

`//*[@id="forecast"]/p[2]/text()`

[image: forecast text]

---

**URL and Xpath in IMPORTXML #1**
[image: forecast01]

**URL and Xpath in IMPORTXML #2**
[image: forecast02]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't get these to work unfortunately.

Comment: Refer my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect!